# Как правильно отформатировать этот файл чтобы он нормально работал с данным кодом Марковых таблиц

Tags: python, файлы

```py
import markovify
import os


with open("/content/khakaton1 (2).txt") as f:
    text = f.read()

text_model = markovify.Text(text)

for i in range(20):
    print(text_model.make_sentence())
```

текст из файла:

```
Без баб.
Денег нет, но вы держитесь.
Это печально.
Это фиаско, братан.
Welcome to the club buddy.
Загадка от Жака Фреско на размышление дается 30 секунд.
Если волк сосал твоего врага это не значит что он стал твоим другом.
Не важно, что не говорят, важно, что говорят.
Сильно, заставляет задуматься.
Чин чан чон чин.
Хорошо.
Ну как там с деньгами?
Какими деньгами?
Вы не понимаете, это другое.
Нет, это то же самое.

А куда?.
Да.
А, понял, спасибо.
Созрел вопрос.
Всем привет, остальным соболезную.
Затем, а главное потому.
Осуждаем.
Даже у него аргументы лучше твоих.
Это по вашему смешно, а ничего, что это ...?
Умные мысли часто преследуют его, но он быстрее.

За что.
Так надо.
Ладно.
Галилео Галилео Галилео.
Кринжовая ситуация...
Взлом жопы.

Я просто хотел банан.
Всем нам стоит поучиться храбрости у него.
Гигант мысли, отец русской демократии.
Хитроумная тактика.
Простите его.
Виновата Америка.

Ахахаххахахахаххахахахахххахах.
Хотя нет, не смешно.
А ведь от такого никто не застрахован.
Вопрос исчерпан).
Добро пожаловать в Саратов.
Сегодня отличный день чтобы любить женщин.
```

Comment: Выдает это
Не важно, что не говорят, важно, что не говорят, важно, что говорят.
None
None
None
None
None
Не важно, что не говорят, важно, что не говорят, важно, что не говорят, важно, что не говорят, важно, что не говорят, важно, что не говорят, важно, что говорят.
Не важно, что не говорят, важно, что не говорят, важно, что говорят.
None
None
None
None
None
Не важно, что говорят.
None
None
None
None
None

Comment: Это текст такой. Тут ничего не исправить - заливайте больше текста. Но это ж так - баловство ж с этой библиотекой и песнями.

Answer (score 0):

Уберите пустые строки - пропадёт None